# Is it possible to check interface up/down using epoll?

Tags: sockets, interface, epoll, ifconfig

I was looking at the source code below.
https://github.com/millken/c-example/blob/master/epoll-example.c

From this source code, the line 140~149 is about error handling when the socket (or file descriptor) has an error.
I wanted to see EPOLLERR occurred and tried to make interface down using "ifconfig [interface name] down" command.

But I don't see EPOLLERR detected from epoll_wait() at line #137.
Is there any way I can generate EPOLLERR condition?
Is it possible to make EPOLLERR condition using interface up/down command?

Comment: Typically the monitoring of network interfaces is done via a separate mechanism -- for example, if you are using Linux, you can create an AF_NETLINK socket and track that socket (using epoll() or similar) to get notifications.  See the route_monitor.c example program here:  https://gist.github.com/cl4u2/5204374

Comment: Does it mean it is not possible to see interface up/down using epoll at all? Or it is possible but it is recommended using separate mechanism?

Comment: I've only used `epoll()` a little bit so I wouldn't rule it out, but my understanding is that what you're looking for isn't what `epoll()` was designed to do.